# Rails ActiveRecord Query for Not Equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails 3.2.1

Is there a way (without [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel)) to use the hash syntax of ActiveRecord to construct a `!=` operator?

Something like `Product.where(id: !params[:id])`

Generates `SELECT products.* FROM products WHERE id != 5`

Looking for the opposite of `Product.where(id: params[:id])`

**UPDATE**

In rails 4 there is a `not` operator.

`Product.where.not(id: params[:id])`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There isn't any built-in way to do this (as of Rails 3.2.13).  However, you can easily build a method to help you out:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.class_eval do
  def self.where_not(opts)
    params = []        
    sql = opts.map{|k, v| params << v; "#{quoted_table_name}.#{quote_column_name k} != ?"}.join(' AND ')
    where(sql, *params)
  end
end
```

And then you can do:

```
Product.where_not(id: params[:id])
```

**UPDATE**

As @DanMclain answered - this is already done for you in Rails 4 (using `where.not(...)`).

Comment: PLUS ONE TO BE SURE.... But be sure to test for nulls too.. They are (to my mind) not equal, but the resulting query will NOT return records where the field has null.  where_not(:status => 'active') for instance..

Comment: Also to be considered... where_not_or   Employee.where(:id=>1).where_not_or(:job_title=>'Awesome', :wages=>10000000).update_all(:job_title=>'Awesome', :wages=>10000000, :updated_at => Time.now)  would only update if things changed

Comment: @daveatflow, SQL standard for NULLs is to _never_ return unless specifically checked using IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.  So I disagree that calling != should modify this behavior.  Adding an `or` method would be greatly beneficial, but at this point using Arel or Squeel is easier than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 93):

You can use the following

```
Product.where('id != ?', params[:id])
```

Which will generate what you are looking for, while parameterizing the query.

With Rails 4, the following syntax has been added to support not clauses

```
Product.where.not(id: params[:id])
```

Add multiple clauses with chaining...

```
Product.where.not(id: params[:id]).where.not(category_id: params[:cat_id])
```

Comment: This may be work unexcepted when params[:id] is nil. In rails 3.2.X I use `Product.where('id != ?', params[:id].to_i)`

Comment: In rails 3, please advise, if there are more than one id, then how to do it? ex. Product.where('id != ?', 10000, 10001, 10004, 10035, 10088)

Answer (score 24):

Rails 4 has this figured out. So maybe you could just update your rails app

```
Model.where.not(:id => params[:id])
```

Comment: Lol, upgrade Rails to improve the syntax of his AR call?  I love it, wish I could go to my management and get some of our old platforms upgraded!

Comment: @MarkKadlec Start your own company   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 14):

**Arel** could the one you might want to explore It is included in Rails 3+ I guess

Here How you do it using **Arel**

```
Product.where(Product.arel_table[:id].not_eq(params[:id]))
```

and

```
Product.where(Product.arel_table[:id].not_eq(params[:id])).to_sql
```

would generate SQL Like below

```
SELECT `products`.* FROM `products`  WHERE (`products`.`id` != 1)
```

Hope this Help

Comment: How to query on multiple attributes using this syntax??

Comment: `.where(…)` can be chained, too, so this extends to searching across multiple columns. `Product.where(…).where(…)`